# Error message while installing Robot Framework

Tags: pip, robotframework

I get an error when trying to install `Desktoplibrary` for robot framework

```
$ pip install robotframework-desktoplibrary
Collecting robotframework-desktoplibrary
  Using cached robotframework-desktoplibrary-1.0.1.zip (15.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgwmj_s_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgwmj_s_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgwmj_s_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\HABLOUSHM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pgwmj_s_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
      NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried to install using pip also I have read some article that I have to install `SikuliLibrary` and I did but still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Library you are trying to install is written for Python2 and you are using  Python3.

`execfile` is not present anymore in python 3 and when setup.py is called, it fails because of this.

You have few choices;

- update the library yourself,
- downgrade to python2
- ask someone to fix the library to support new python.
- switch to https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary